# Java Vectors for a Two Player Card Game

Tags: java, vector

So this is a homework assignment that I have been struggling to understand.  Provided was a Card class that includes each card suit, rank, and value for the given assignment.  The instructor does not want us to use arrays due to the fact that we have not covered them yet, so I am stuck with Vectors.

The problem that I am having is with the Vector playerPile.  It is only displaying the first two suits (i.e. Ace of Clubs - King of Clubs, and Ace of Hearts - King of Hearts).  Yes this breaks the cards from the Vector deck up into a Vector playerPile of 26 like I want but how do I allow all 52 of the cards to be possibilities in that Vector playerPile?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import card.Card;
import yesnoextractor.YesNoExtractor;


public class Peace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector deck = new Vector();
        for(int i = 1; i < 53; i++){
            Card card = new Card(i);
            System.out.println(card);
            deck.add(card);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        System.out.println(deck);

        Vector playerPile = new Vector();
        for(int i = 1; i < 27; i++){
            Card card = new Card(i);
            playerPile.add(card);
            deck.remove(card);
            Collections.shuffle(playerPile);
        }
        System.out.println(playerPile);
```

I am hoping that this is an easy fix but just can't seem to figure out my logical error.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Best Regards,
Dan

Comment: Why are you creating new cards in your second loop?  (This is a rhetorical question.)

Comment: Do you want to include all 52 cards into the playerPile, or do you want to randomize? (The latter is not needed because of the `Collections.shuffle()` call)